# Not able to install Collabnet Subversion 5.0.1 on Win 2008 Server

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008, collabnet

We are upgrading our Windows server from 2003 to 2008.
On Win 2003, we were using Collabnet Subversion 1.7.7, as we upgraded server to Win 2008, SVN stopped working. We found that Collabnet SVN 5.0.1 has support for Win 2008, but we are not able to install it.

We are getting 'disk1.cab has invalid signature' while installing Collabnet Subversion 5.0.1 (32 bit) on Win 2008 server(32 bit).

Any help is solicited.
Regards

P.S: We found that Collabnet SVN 5.0.1 uses SHA2, Seems invalid signature has to do with it. Is there any hotfix for Win 2008 to support SHA2 or it has inbuilt support for it?

Comment: Server 2008 supports SHA2, but that doesn't mean that the installer is using it properly. Have you tried downloading a fresh copy, to make sure the file isn't corrupted? Also, why are you setting up a *new* server with an OS that's 6 months past the end of Mainstream support and no longer getting service packs? Get on a current OS.

Comment: Thanks Alroc, We were upgrading Win 2003 to Win 2008. Installing svn after upgrade was not working. Once we installed fresh Win 2008 and tried installing SVN there, it worked.

Comment: "We were upgrading Win 2003 to Win 2008" Again, why aren't you upgrading to a **current** OS? This late in the game, 2003 to 2008 is very nearly a lateral move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'disk1.cab has invalid signature' error definitely refers to the lack of support for sha2 signatures. I believe the up-to-date Win 2008 supports sha2 signatures. Were you able to try installing on a fresh download?

Relevant issue : [Try here](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=549592#messagefocus)

**Update:**: A new version of the 5.0.1 has been made available that resolves this problem. Just download again and it should work.

The installers are using the newer sha256 certificates and some versions of Windows cannot validate them. There are hot fixes available but they do not resolve all issues. The installer has been signed again in a way that is backwards compatible.

[Click here](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=559610) for further follow-up

Comment: yes, I tried downloading it multiple times. Installing SVN on freshWin 2008 worked.

Comment: A new version of the 5.0.1 has been made available. Please read the description again.